# GridView with 2 items in each row

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to show two GridViewItems in each row, with equal width. how can I achieve that?

I am using following template but it is not taking equal space between items.

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="GridViewItemTestTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">               
            <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,9.5,0,0">
                <Image Height="79" Width="79"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="14.5,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Subtitle" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

here is my gridview.

```
  <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GridViewItemTestTemplate}" 
                  IsSwipeEnabled="False" SelectionMode="Single" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        </GridView>
```

Comment: Try setting the width on both of your template grid ColumnDefinition to Width=".5*"

Answer (score 1):

Replace your StackPanel with this

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="14.5,0,0,0"> 
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Subtitle" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Grids resize themselves dynamically versus StackPanels. The `ColumnDefinition Width="*"` is the important part, telling the panel to set the width of each column to fill the width of the grid, and for each column to have the same width.

---

edit: Is this the hehavior you want? Not as pretty as dynamic resizing but the same width requirement with 2 items per row basically force all items to have the same width

```
<GridView Width="200">
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</GridView>
```

Comment: You did not get my question... I want 2 items in each row.... 
see the updated question

Comment: Ah, okay, the solution then is to use a fixed width for your entire GridView. Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533105/how-to-control-number-of-items-appearing-in-gridview-rows-and-columns-in-a-metro) what you're looking for?